# When position is bigger, linear background color will be stronger

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could anyone guide me on how to change the background from yellow to red?
I have made this that only when the position is 700+, the background color will be red.

.danger is `.danger {background-color: #d82505;}`

```
            $.each(allSpans, function (i, e) {
            if ($(e).position().left > 850) {
                clearAllIntervals();
            } else if ($(e).position().left > 700 && $(e).position().left < 710) {
                $(e).addClass('danger')
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `$(e).css("background-color","yellow");`. But you will have to make sure that the CSS class doesn't override your style. So, it would be best to assign the color like this for all such cases without using classes.

Or, if you do want to use classes, use `$(el).removeClass('classForRedBG').addClass('classForYellowBg');`. However, imagine doing that for multiple classes, that's a lot of manual work. You'll have to do this in a smart way as a coder.